# Extracting the hyperlink from multiple cells with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to iterate through a column, and extract each hyperlink to be used in the code (going to compare it to some text).

Any good pointers on how to do the extraction part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.Hyperlinks(1).Address` to get the Hyperlinks

For example this will extract the hyperlinks from A1 to A5

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print Range("A" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You also might want to do error handling to ensure that the code doesn't break if there are no hyperlinks in the cell...

Comment: Thx, but the for this specific purpose I do know that each cell has a hyperlink.

Comment: Use .SubAddress if the link is to within the same document.