# Excel Script Hyperlink Extraction

Tags: excel, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting the hyperlink from multiple cells with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289664/extracting-the-hyperlink-from-multiple-cells-with-vba)

[FIXED] Sorted it myself :)

> For i = 3 To total
>
> ```
> Cells(i, 11) = Cells(i, 1).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
> Cells(i, 12) = Cells(i, 2).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
>
>  Next i
> ```

I've never done any scripting in excel so any help appreciated.

I want to extract the hyperlink address (URL) from columns 1 & 2. And paste them (not as hyperlinks) into another column (so I can export to CSV with links)

I want to do something like this in a loop, but it doesn't work!

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address


ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to get all the hyperlinks in the first two columns of a sheet and write them to the next sheet.

```
Sub getHyperlinks()
'used to keep track of where we are at when writing to the second sheet
Dim iWriteRow As Long
'used to hold how many columns to look through
Dim numberOfCols As Long
numberOfCols = 2
'set initial position
iWriteRow = 1

'variable used in looping through the hyperlinks
Dim h As Hyperlink
'loop through all hyper links on the sheet
For i = 1 To numberOfCols
    For Each h In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(i).Hyperlinks
        'write them to the next sheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(iWriteRow, i).Value = h.Address
        'add 1 to our counter
        iWriteRow = iWriteRow + 1
    Next
    iWriteRow = 1
Next i
End Sub
```